# Using large txt files in JavaFX(TextArea alternatives?)

Tags: java, javafx

I created a simple GUI where I have a `TextArea`. The `TextArea` itself will be populated by an `Array`, which contains scanned Strings out of a `.txt` file.

This works great for smaller size files. When using large files(~5MB per txt.-file) however, the `TextArea`(and only the `TextArea`) feels laggy and slow(not as responsive as I would like). Is there an alternative to the `TextArea`(doesnt have to be in `JavaFX`)?

I'm looking for something very simple, which basically allows me to get & set text. `Slidercontrol`, as in `JavaFX` `TextArea`, would be very handy.

Thank you and have a great day!

Edit: a very basic example of my code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

public void start(Stage stage) {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    TextField filePath = new TextField("Filepath goes in here...");
    TextArea file = new TextArea("Imported file strings go here...");
    file.relocate(0, 60);
    Button btnImport = new Button("Import file");
    btnImport.relocate(0, 30);
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

    btnImport.setOnAction(e -> {
        File fileToImport = new File(filePath.getText());
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileToImport);
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                data.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            file.setText(data.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    pane.getChildren().addAll(filePath, file, btnImport);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch();
}
}
```

Comment: most high volume data controls in Java have 'virtual mode', to provide only part of data (required rows). But it isnt simple like get & set

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the code.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Here is an example, as described in the guideline(edit the start post)

Comment: Well, the first thing you can do is get rid of that Scanner and replace it with a BufferedReader. The second thing you can do is replace that ArrayList. You can either append text directly to the TextArea or first use a StringBuilder, then add the text to the TextArea.

Comment: Have you tried the ListView?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I´m using the imported strings to filter them later on, that´s why I was storing them in an ArrayList(so I can use the retrieved data, without having to read it later on out of the TextArea). I will try ListView later on, since I´m inexperienced with it. Thank you!

Comment: @SedrickJefferson ListView worked great! It runs very smooth now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on @Matt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819049/230513) and @SedrickJefferson's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796527/using-large-txt-files-in-javafxtextarea-alternatives#comment76607059_44796527), here's a complete example.

[image]

```
import java.io.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox pane = new VBox();
        Button importButton = new Button("Import");
        TextField filePath = new TextField("/usr/share/dict/words");
        ObservableList<String> lines = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(lines);
        importButton.setOnAction(a -> {
            listView.getItems().clear();
            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
                    (new FileReader(filePath.getText())); 
                String s;
                while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    listView.getItems().add(s);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        pane.getChildren().addAll(importButton, filePath, listView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @SedrickJefferson I replaced the `TextArea` with a `ListView`. It runs very smooth now. Besides that I will replace the `Scanner` with a `BufferedReader`, due to performance issues.